# Linq multiple levels in

Tags: c#, linq

I have three tables joined as parent / child / grandchild.

I am trying to obtain a Linq query that shows the records from parent table and a collection of grandchild table. I do not want to show the child table because that's a jonction table containing threee IDs only.

What I've got so far is

```
var list = (from r in ctx.Roles.Include(x => x.RolesResources.Select(z => z.Resources)) select r)
    .ToList()
```

It kind of works. I am not happy with the result because the parent element (r in Roles) contains a collection of child elements (RolesResources) and each of those contain one entry of Resources.

What I actually need is that r in Roles to have a collection of Resources, skipping the middle table.

Is this even possible? if yes, what I have missed?

Comment: Well, please disregard. You know when you find the answer to your problem while explaining it to someone else? That's what happened.

`var list = (from r in ctx.Roles
                                select new
                                {
                                    r.Id,
                                    r.Name,
                                    r.IsAdmin,
                                    r.IsActive,
                                    Resources = r.RolesResources.Select(p => p.Resources)
                                }).ToList();`

Comment: If you've found the answer to your question, consider posting an answer below, if you think it will be helpful to others. Worst case, if you think this won't be helpful, then remove the question altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's completely possible, using either an anonymous object or a helper class. Supposing that you will need this outside of the current method, I'll show with a class.

```
public class RolesViewModel
{
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    public List<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
}

var list = ctx.Roles
    .Select(r => new RolesViewModel
    {
        Role = r,
        Resources = r.RolesResources.Select(rr => rr.Resources).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. I've got a pretty similar solution, posted it in a comment but Stackoverflow is beating me. How the heck I add code in comments? :) tried with backticks, no go.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @GrigoreDolghin: Backticks `should work`, but the general answer is: You don't. If you have an answer (even if it's to your own question), write it as an answer, not as a comment. Putting answers in comments is deliberately hard to discourage people from doing it.

Comment: @Heinzi - meanwile Camilo gave a much cleaner answer, so I accepted that one as an answer. Thank you

Comment: @GrigoreDolghin Yes, you should avoid posting code in comments as much as possible, because it's pretty hard to read. Also, do notice that it's encouraged to post your own answer to your question if there are no answers that work or are good enough. Glad to have helped.